# Substitute words for characters between matches in a line?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

The raw text is like this:

```
<words> command feed world </words> tag=random      
<words> who is that ? </words> tag=normal
```

I need to substitute words for characters:

```
<words> c o m m a n d  f e e d  w o r l d </words> tag=random
<words> w h o  i s  t h a t ? </words> tag=normal
```

I know how to do it if the range is over lines, but don't know how to do it if the range is in a line..

My solution:

```
%s:<words>.*\zs(.)\ze.*</words>:\1 :gc
```

Without any doubt it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've formatted that example correctly? Some
of the spacing seems a bit arbitrary and doesn't seem
straightforward to get right:

```
:%s:\(<words> .*\)\@<=\a\( \A\)\@!\(.* </words>\)\@=:& :g
```

In particular see `:h \@<=` for checking for the existence of a preceding
item, and `:h \@!` and `:h \@=` for negative and positive assertions
at the cursor position.